# How to trigger an event when all subscribers received the item on RxJava2?

Tags: java, rx-java2

I've developed a consumer/producer on RxJava, based on the following article [rxjava2 producer-consumer example](https://www.sothawo.com/2017/04/rxjava2-producer-consumer-example-with-backpressure-implementation/).

But my usecase is a little more complicated.

I'll be using multiple subscribers, each one with some sort of filter (the amount of subscribers and its filters will vary at runtime), and there will be some itens which will not be processed by any of the subscribers.

I need to get all the remaining items (that did not qualify for any of the subscribers) to do some post processing.

I've tried to use the method "onAfterNext()" on the producer, but ths method executes before the item is processed by the Subscribers

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this using `PublishSubject` class to append my listeners.

```
PublishSubject<SQSMessage<String>> ps = PublishSubject.create()
ps.publish();
ps.subscribe(m -> System.err.println(m));

flowable.parallel()
    .runOn(Schedulers.io())
    .map(item -> {   
        // This map sends the object to my listeners on PublishSubject
        ps.onNext(item);
       return item;
    })
    .sequential()
    // This map does the post processing after
    // the object was sent to the listeners
    .map(s -> {//do post process stuff})
    .subscribe();
```